# Unable to find P4 executable at path 'p4'

Tags: teamcity, perforce

Setting Version Control Settings in Teamcity by Perfoce as CVS type, typed "p4" in Path to P4 executable. then click "save" and "Test connection", then alerts "Unable to find P4 executable at path 'p4'".
Anybody meets this issue while integrate Teamcity with Perforce?

Answer (score 2):

The path to the P4 executable is not `p4`, it's typically

`C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe`